# Messaging framework for a linux cluster using TIPC

Tags: linux, sockets, messaging, tipc

I am trying to learn/design a messaging framework on a linux based carrier grade box. the legacy design that i have uses sockets to achieve the same.

I have been evaluating TIPC since it is optimized for intra cluster IPC, hence faster, more reliable and supports feature such as multicast.

I am pretty comfortable with sockets and good with concepts, But new to TIPC.

What i am lacking is detailed examples of TIPC(socket client/server examples are available in tons) and also insight into TIPC addressing concept.

From whatever i read so far, programming is going to be similar to that of sockets since its part of linux kernel, i would appreciate any help that gives me more details onto how to design tipc nodes.

Comment: I found some excellent demo examples [here](http://tipc.sourceforge.net/tipc_linux.shtml). So with that i have found answer to my question :). However i am always open to discuss design aspects to improve my learning curve

Answer (score 1):

I found some excellent demo examples [here](http://tipc.sourceforge.net/tipc_linux.shtml). So with that i have found answer to my question :). However i am always open to discuss design aspects to improve my learning curve